# How to improve System.Tuple with shrink, toArray and fromArray methods

Tags: c#, arrays, tuples

I need to implements a method regards System.Tuple class in .Net. What is the best way to do it? Expansion methods, subclass entire set of Tuple classes or create a new class based on source code of System.Tuple?

The method gets in input a `Tuple<T1,T2..Tn>` and return a `Tuple<T1..Tm>  (m<n)` based  on a mask (int or boolean). How can I replace the switch-case statements and the use of Reflections? How can I improve performance?

```
public static object shrink(this object source, params int[] mask)
{
    PropertyInfo[] prop = source.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().ToArray<PropertyInfo>();
    object[] tmp = new object[mask.Length];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.Length; i++)
    {
        if (mask[i] != 0)
        {
            tmp[index] = prop[i].GetValue(source, null);
            index++;
        }
    }
    switch (index)
    {
        case 1: return Tuple.Create(tmp[0]);
        case 2: return Tuple.Create(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
            ....
            ....
    }
}
```

In the same way I need to implement a `Tuple` to Array and an Array to `Tuple` method.

```
2) public static object toArray(this object source)
```

Input: `Tuple<T1..Tn>`  Output: `object[]`

```
3) public static object FromArray(this object source)
```

Input: `object[]`       Output `Tuple<T1..Tn)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probally not improve the runtime of the function, but it will avoid the switch case.

```
private object StripTuple(object tuple, int[] mask)
{
    int[] indexes = mask.Select((v, i) => new { val = v, index = i }).Where(o => o.val == 1).Select(i => i.index).ToArray();
    object[] items = new object[indexes.Length];
    Type[] tupleTypes = new Type[indexes.Length];
    var originalTupleType = tuple.GetType();
    var genericArgs = originalTupleType.GetGenericArguments();

    for (var i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
    {
        items[i] = originalTupleType.GetProperty("Item" + (indexes[i] + 1)).GetValue(tuple);
        tupleTypes[i] = genericArgs[indexes[i]];
    }

    Type tupleType = Type.GetType("System.Tuple`" + indexes.Length);
    Type newTupleType = tupleType.MakeGenericType(tupleTypes);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(newTupleType, items);
}
```

Usage:

```
var t1 = new Tuple<int, int, int, string, double, string, int>(1, 2, 3, "4", 5.7, "6", 7);
var newTuple = StripTuple(t1, new int[7]{0,0,0,1,1,0,1}); // "4",5.7,7
```

The function will take the first m params(m <= tuple's length).
If the input is `Tuple<int,int,string,int>` and length = 3 then the output type will be `Tuple<int,int,string>`

Comment: Your code take the first m elements of the Tuple. I will change a bit your code to get a subset of the tuple based on the mask  e.g.(1,0,1,0= the first and the third elements only).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid reflection your only option is to create overloads for all Tuple, Tuple.. generic tuple types:

```
public static object shrink<T1>(this Tuple<T1> tuple, params int[] mask) {
}

public static object shrink<T1, T2>(this Tuple<T1, T2> tuple, params int[] mask) {
}

...
```

Same for ToArray() method. Return types for FromArray and Shrink will stay "object" though anyway, because you return different tuples, and they do not share any usable public class or interface. Why do you need to do that at all? I have a feeling you may not need to use Tuple classes for your task.

Comment: I use very often `List<Tuple<T1..Tn>>` to save and elaborate CSV files. I think I can use `List<List<object>>` or something else, but the question is: why Tuple calsses are so poor?

Comment: Well their only purpose is to hold together multiple variables and not create your own type for that. So they are poor because they serve simple goal.

Answer (score 0):

1) This is same as Amir's answer, just more LINQ-ish.

```
public static object shrink(this object source, params int[] mask)
{
    var props = source.GetType().GetProperties();
    var values = mask
                .Select((val, index) => new { val, index })
                .Where(x => x.val != 0)
                .Select(x => props[x.index])
                .Select(prop => new { prop, value = prop.GetValue(source) })
                .ToList();

    var type = Type.GetType("System.Tuple`" + values.Count)
              .MakeGenericType(values.Select(x => x.prop.PropertyType).ToArray());
    var arguments = values.Select(x => x.value).ToArray();
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type, arguments);
}
```

2) If it fits you could return a dynamic type that dynamically decides the definition. Something like:

```
public static object shrink(this object source, params int[] mask)
{
    var props = source.GetType().GetProperties();
    var items = mask
               .Select((val, index) => new { val, index })
               .Where(x => x.val != 0)
               .Select((x, index) => new
               {
                   name = "Item" + index,
                   val = props[x.index].GetValue(source)
               })
               .ToList();

    var expando = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
    foreach (var item in items)
        expando[item.name] = item.val;

    return expando;
}
```

3) Lastly you should be able to use expression trees and use pre-compiled delegates instead of reflection to generate the run-time tuple, but since this whole thing is not generic you will have to use `DynamicInvoke` which will be slower, so I am not sure of the performance gain. `DynamicInvoke`s are terribly slow and among the slowest constructs in the framework. If performance matters you can write individual overloads like Evk has shown.